# Selecting maximum varchar casted into a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am attempting to get the maximum Decimal value from a column and then add 1 to it to get the next value. However, the column's values are of type varchar, meaning that I must filter to make sure that it only attempts to cast values it can, like '123,' while avoiding values like '123a'

What I have attempted so far is this:

```
SELECT
  (CAST(MAX(Id) AS DECIMAL(38,0)) + 1) AS 'New ID'
FROM database
WHERE Id NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' --filters out non-numeric ID values
  AND (LEN(Id) + 1) < 39     --ensures ID is less than length 39
```

However, when I run this, if a value such as 9 and a value such as 100 exist in the ID column, MAX will prioritize the 9 over the 100.

I've also attempted:

```
SELECT
  (CAST(MAX(CAST(Id AS DECIMAL(38,0))) AS DECIMAL(38,0)) + 1) AS 'New ID'
FROM database
WHERE Id NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
  AND (LEN(Id) + 1) < 39
```

However, this results in an error converting varchar into numeric, since I'm assuming it attempts to cast it as a decimal before filtering out the non-numeric IDs in the WHERE clause. I've also tried getting rid of the extra cast at the start, but that still has the same issue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: switch the order so the cast occurs before the max. `MAX(CAST(Id AS DECIMAL(38,0)) + 1) AS 'New ID'` or something like that.. or use a CTE to first eliminate the non-numeric IDs and then cast to get the max + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is empty strings. Your condition: *Id NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'* is true when Id is the empty string. This should work:

```
SELECT
  (MAX(CAST(Id AS DECIMAL(38,0)))  + 1) AS 'New ID'
FROM database
WHERE Id NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
   AND Id <> ''
   AND (LEN(Id) + 1) < 39
```

The outer CAST is redundant (MAX will return the same type as its argument).

PS: The WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT clause, so if you filter out the invalid values in the WHERE, conversions in the SELECT will not fail.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `try_convert()`:

```
SELECT MAX(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 0), id)) + 1 AS [New ID]
FROM database
WHERE Id NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND (LEN(Id) + 1) < 39 ;
```

Your example converts back to a decimal, but I think you want a string:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(38), MAX(TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 0), id)) + 1) AS [New ID]
FROM database
WHERE Id NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' AND (LEN(Id) + 1) < 39 ;
```

The problem that you are facing is based on how SQL Server processes queries.  We *intend* that the `WHERE` clause is processed before the `SELECT`.  However, that might not be how the calculation gets set up.  So, SQL Server ends up doing unnecessary work on converting values that will get filtered out -- but then an error occurs interrupting the query.

In my opinion, this is an error in the implementation of SQL Server.  One presumes that they have a good reason for allowing errors to flow through, even when the rows are not being selected.  We can all agree that it is an inconvenience.

Before `TRY_CONVERT()`, the `CASE` statement would be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First cast to decimal, then get the maximum (numeric) value (so 10 > 9), then add 1, then cast to string if necessary.

```
SELECT
  CAST(MAX(CAST(Id AS DECIMAL(38,0))) + 1) AS VARCHAR(39)) AS [New ID]
FROM database
WHERE Id NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
  AND LEN(Id) < 39;
```